# Checking fields in related entities with mongoose/mongodb operators

Tags: mongodb, rest, express, validation, mongoose

So, I'm developing a REST API and recently one solid issue came up. I have a multiple entities with "one-to-many" relationship, basically the very simplified schema would look like this:

[image]

So what do I have here is **FeedEntry** entity which has field 'feed'(an ID) which points to **Feed** entity, and same for **Feed** having a 'space' field which is an ID of a corresponding **Space** entity.

The problem comes when I'm trying to retrieve particular **FeedEntry** by ID, since there is a special condition.

Each **Space** entity has an array of member users IDs and 'owner' field which is also a user ID. What I need to identify, is whether the user who requests **FeedEntry** is a member/owner of a **Space** which contains corresponding **Feed**(and the requested **FeedEntry** should point to this **Feed** with its 'feed' field). So far, my 'best' solution for this kind of validation is like following:

```
async (id, { req: { user } }) => {
  const entry = await FeedEntry.findById(id);
  const parentFeed = await Feed.findById(entry.feed);
  const isMember = parentFeed && await Space.exists({
    _id: parentFeed.space,
    $or: [{ members: user._id }, { owner: user._id }]
  });
  if (!isMember)
    return Promise.reject('Issuer has no access to this feed entry.');
}
```

As for me this looks quite clumsy and I'm sure there is a much better way of doing stuff like that with some advanced features of Mongoose and/or MongoDB. Any help would be appreciated.

**UPD**

Schemas code

```
const SpaceSchema = new Schema({
  _id: { type: String, default: generate },
  name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  owner: { type: String, required: true },
  members: [{ type: String }]
});

const FeedSchema = new Schema({
  _id: { type: String, default: generate },
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  owner: { type: String, required: true },
  space: { type: String, required: true },
  entries: [{ type: String }]
});

const FeedEntrySchema = new Schema({
  _id: { type: String, default: generate },
  author: { type: String, required: true },
  header: { type: String, required: true },
  content: { type: String, required: true },
  feed: { type: String, required: true },
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: new Date().toISOString() },
  edited: { type: Boolean, default: false }
});
```

Sample docs

FeedEntry:

```
_id: "SNdmSx6G"
createdAt: 2020-01-04T18:33:35.117+00:00
edited: false
author: "ADPKXAHm"
header: "Test entry 2"
content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commo..."
feed: "c6zarBHg"
__v:0
```

Feed:

```
_id: "c6zarBHg"
entries:
  Array
    0: "1v40fOpj"
    1: "SNdmSx6G"
name: "Tst 2.3"
owner: "6FyfkAGX"
space: "b_mBKcd4"
__v: 0
```

Space:

```
_id: "b_mBKcd4"
members:
  Array
    0: "ADPKXAHm"
name: "Tst 2"
owner: "6FyfkAGX"
__v: 0
```

Comment: Please post your schemas code to the question as text, and provide sample dcos.

Comment: @SuleymanSah posted samples, note: I'm using shortId instead of regular ObjectId from mongo

Comment: So what do you want to achieve? Do you want to decrease the number of db access?

Comment: Kind of, maybe there is possibility to combine queries instead of doing two separate findById queries for Feed and FeedEntry

Comment: Maybe this can be done using aggregation,  plesae update your sample documents in your question as json.